# Error in polygon used to shade are behind curve

Tags: r

I have read all the entries of questions like this but I didn't find anything that could help, this is my polygon to fill the right side of the curve and I can't see the error, there is a blank space but I gave the parameters to the polygon to paint that zone, it should be traveling the x axis form the max to mu2, the other polygon is doing what it should, thanks.

NEW: When I use a value like 7 or 6.4 for mu2 it works well so this make me think about a precision problem of polygon

```
polygon(c(xDMedia[xDMedia>=mu2], max(xDMedia), mu2), c(yDMedia[xDMedia>=mu2], 0, 0), col="limegreen")
```

[image: Result]

My xDMedia, yDmedia and mu2

> dput(xDMedia, file="")
> c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2,
> 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5,
> 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8,
> 3.9, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5, 5.1,
> 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4,
> 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7,
> 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9,
> 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10, 10.1, 10.2,
> 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, 11, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3,
> 11.4, 11.5, 11.6, 11.7, 11.8, 11.9, 12, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.4,
> 12.5)

> dput(yDMedia, file="")
> c(2.91071142910227e-82, 1.10926411127833e-79, 3.84243474140259e-77,
> 1.20980051630087e-74, 3.46223671717269e-72, 9.00607329524449e-70,
> 2.12936407901061e-67, 4.57614837111116e-65, 8.93893949294461e-63,
> 1.58711218236391e-60, 2.56132671885352e-58, 3.75714591310782e-56,
> 5.00941337026839e-54, 6.07087661775062e-52, 6.68731328774676e-50,
> 6.69557161598033e-48, 6.09339563028007e-46, 5.04042110123589e-44,
> 3.7897450322893e-42, 2.58993515548028e-40, 1.60880540328268e-38,
> 9.08351355772525e-37, 4.66165306005012e-35, 2.17451173157962e-33,
> 9.21975305268927e-32, 3.5531418805206e-30, 1.24463364754488e-28,
> 3.96283739528478e-27, 1.14685019991037e-25, 3.01677460646759e-24,
> 7.21298053131184e-23, 1.56755354046466e-21, 3.09646184992561e-20,
> 5.55961619165646e-19, 9.07318185517198e-18, 1.34589180012959e-16,
> 1.8146647614828e-15, 2.22391606249654e-14, 2.47728574960278e-13,
> 2.50824262698434e-12, 2.30833433393913e-11, 1.93091699634494e-10,
> 1.46812903059323e-09, 1.01461335532865e-08, 6.37342162948102e-08,
> 3.63898656538713e-07, 1.8885304066174e-06, 8.9084723863252e-06,
> 3.81960296432222e-05, 0.000148856886959275, 0.00052729708451961,
> 0.00169776483839989, 0.00496861592212148, 0.0132168830055172,
> 0.0319564399623262, 0.0702301287836083, 0.14028920849758, 0.254718678090965,
> 0.420371289102378, 0.63058121346906, 0.859774848703654, 1.06552629564871,
> 1.20027105919226, 1.22893871027206, 1.14371242981923, 0.967473737806807,
> 0.743870362549812, 0.519865567780754, 0.33023308285217, 0.190671521012533,
> 0.100066062307262, 0.0477335260360562, 0.0206964543500554, 0.00815650506750984,
> 0.0029217832690901, 0.000951322158217698, 0.00028154184618683,
> 7.57345453989195e-05, 1.85174345667749e-05, 4.11531744879845e-06,
> 8.31307294951317e-07, 1.52635505251474e-07, 2.5473303660636e-08,
> 3.86412088085459e-09, 5.32784844177531e-10, 6.67711333042491e-11,
> 7.60608824926594e-12, 7.87534701653917e-13, 7.41163060617022e-14,
> 6.34006280001235e-15, 4.92957048177859e-16, 3.48385706239622e-17,
> 2.23793414794791e-18, 1.30668229024679e-19, 6.93471207393019e-21,
> 3.34520386719062e-22, 1.46673776221262e-23, 5.84545179743867e-25,
> 2.11748050656072e-26, 6.97198566229517e-28, 2.08655230915465e-29,
> 5.67593999266055e-31, 1.40340183798832e-32, 3.15400235795335e-34,
> 6.44284544657156e-36, 1.19626980345074e-37, 2.01890690885152e-39,
> 3.09698552296497e-41, 4.31815058576688e-43, 5.47257999378072e-45,
> 6.30408674809515e-47, 6.60066922802799e-49, 6.28187783543625e-51,
> 5.43408878423434e-53, 4.27267343345645e-55, 3.05357364022831e-57,
> 1.9835941674145e-59, 1.17120515263888e-61, 6.28563058264317e-64,
> 3.06619985732502e-66, 1.35952685926749e-68, 5.47912050418579e-71,
> 2.00710290379337e-73, 6.68288754930985e-76, 2.0225273108125e-78,
> 5.56365719526309e-81)

> dput(mu2, file="")
> 6.90904630446145

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten Maybe a precision problem of polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because a precision error of the polygon function or because the number of points that define the distribution line, the solution is to round it:

```
mu2<-round(mu2, 1)
```